# Change CD File System

Tags: filesystems, compact-disc, livecd

I recently used UDF format for my CD so I can play some music on my car but when I insert it in, it shows me that it only supports Joliet/ISO9660 (My CD is also a live file system).

So is there any tool that i can switch the file system for the CD?

If not, What tool I can use to create file system Joliet/ISO9660 (using a new CD)?

Comment: That’s the most basic CD format. You’ll be hard-pressed to find CD burning software that does *not* support it.

Comment: @DanielB thanks so the software can also change the format from UDF to Joliet?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. When you author a CD, you get to choose the format. Perhaps you should better explain (by editing the question) what your goal is.

Comment: @DanielB i just want to see if there is any software/tool allows me to change CD file system type

Comment: Change it on the already burned disc? No such thing exists.

Comment: You have to burn a new disc, and before doing so set the appropriate setting in whichever burner software you are using to write using the Joliet/ISO9660 format.

Comment: @music2myear thanks and the disk is not mastered and so I need a software to set it or I can just use the windows popup prompt?

Comment: @zhiyan114 It's irrelevant. You just can do that in write-once media whether closed or not. Rewritable media can be erased and when burned again a different format can be chosen.